# How to construct a Predicate Indicator?

Tags: prolog

I want to use the ISO `current_predicate/1` predicate, but with a constructed argument (the "predicate indicator").

So rather than querying the predicate indicator literally, like `current_predicate(foo/1)`, I want to do something like

```
check_pred(P):-
   ???(P,1,P1),
   current_predicate(P1). % P1 must be a predicate indicator
check_pred(foo).
```

For the `???`, neither `functor(P1, P, 1)` works (as it constructs a term), nor `atom_concat(P, '/1', P1)` (as it constructs an atom).

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `(/)/2, That is `P1 = P/1`

Comment: @false Beautiful. Make it an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting @false comment to an answer:

> Use `(/)/2`, That is `P1 = P/1`